# can not upload files to a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I developed a mobile application on Android with a WebView view.
On the site I put in the webview there is a place where can upload a file except that with the webview when I click on the place to file a upload it does not matter.
while normally he should offer me to open the file manager but I have nothing.
Please help me
I attach the code of my webview below

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public String StartUrl = "https://app.vetotrack.com/?tokenPhoneValue=";
public String token;
public String EndUrl = "&tokenPhoneOs=android";
public String Url;


public String getValueToken() {

    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("tag", "getValueToken: " + refreshedToken);
    return refreshedToken;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //Cacher le Title Bar
    MyFirebaseMessagingService mf = new MyFirebaseMessagingService();
    mf.onNewToken(token);
    token = getValueToken();
    Url = StartUrl + token + EndUrl;
    WebView mywebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("app.vetotrack.com")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        }
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    mywebView.loadUrl(Url);


} }
```

A permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.androidtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AdvanceWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java), see if this works